# Reading HTML5 input radio tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know if there is a one line approach without loops for reading the value of radio input in HTML5.

In the old HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

The javascript is like:

```
var sexes = document.getElementsByName('sex');
var sex_value;
for(var i = 0; i < sexes.length; i++){
    if(sexes[i].checked){
        sex_value = sexes[i].value;
    }
}
```

But the same can be done with Jquery in one line like

```
$('input[name="sex"]:checked').val();
```

So I just want to know:

1. Is a better way of doing it in HTML5 without Jquery?
2. Is there any other JS library like Jquery that can do the same one-line approach or better?

Comment: Reading the the values to do what?

Comment: why not use jquery if you want a one-line approach? Btw.. too much sex goin' on between your variables .. `sexes`, `sex_value`, `sexes.length`.. kidding

Comment: Why would you want to look outside jQuery? If it works, why does it matter if there's another library that returns similar results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [JavaScript] is like:

```
var sexes = document.getElementsByName('sex');
var sex_value;
for(var i = 0; i < sexes.length; i++){
    if(sexes[i].checked){
        sex_value = sexes[i].value;
    }
}
```

> But the same can be done with Jquery in one line like

```
$('input[name="sex"]:checked').val();
```

The same can be done in one line in the native DOM/JavaScript:

```
// using a CSS selector to retrieve a single DOM node,
// and retrieving its value property:
document.querySelector('input[name=sex]:checked').value;
```

Or, to get *all* elements, should they be checkboxes for example:

```
// using a CSS selector to retrieve all matching elements
// as a (non-live) NodeList:
var all = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=favourites]:checked');
```

To retrieve the values of all these checkboxes, into an array:

```
// retrieving the elements into a NodeList:
var all = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=favourites]:checked'),
    // using Array.prototype.slice() (with
    // Function.prototype.call()) to convert
    // the NodeList into an Array:
    allArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(all, 0),
    // using Array.prototype.map() to iterate over that
    // array to return another array containing only
    // the values of each of the array-elements:
    allValues = allArray.map(function (arrayElement) {
                    return arrayElement.value;
                });
```

Which can be condensed into a mere few lines, if you really wanted to (skipping the call to `Array.prototype.slice()`):

```
var allValues = Array.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=favourites]:checked', function (arrayElement) {
    return arrayElement.value;
});
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for answers like yours. I was not aware of a one line solution without Jquery. Please link me to a page where you think I can understand more about DOM in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

1. is there a better way without using jQuery? without loops and a one liner? no
2. is there another library like jQuery that can do the one-liner better? no

the real question is then, why the aversion to jQuery? jQuery is well tested and accepted by the community so much so that there are countless js libraries that build off of jQuery.

Comment: I have no issue with Jquery. But I am aware of other libraries like Mootools. I am a backend developer, just want to update my html, js & css skills.

Comment: jQuery it's the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you can use the [`RadioNodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList) property, which is [part of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0). However, it is apparently not supported by IE 8 and older, and support in mobile browsers is unknown according to MDN.

More exactly, you start from a `form` element, where the `elements` property has a `namedItem` method, which returns a `RadioNodeList` object when the value of a `name` attribute is given as argument. The object has the `value` property, which yields the value of the currently checked radio buttons in the group identified by the name.

Example:

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
<br>
<button type=button onclick=show()>Show sex</button>
</form>
<script>
function show() {
  alert(document.forms[0].elements.namedItem('sex').value)
}
</script>
```

Whether this is better than some other approach is a matter of opinion and depends on context and scope. The question about alternate libraries is off-topic at SO.

Comment: Off-topic: The snippet section is neat. How did you do it??

Comment: @qbektrix: above the editing panel of questions and answers, there's a button that looks like a page with `</>` on it, click that button and it brings up an editor (only for HTML, CSS and JavaScript though).

Comment: This doesn't work in IE 11.